# Middleware in Express

Tags: node.js

How to catch the error which is throwing in middleware function in router(/test) method

```js
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {    
        throw new Error('test');
      next("its failing")    
    })

    app.get('/test',function(req,res,error){

      res.send({ message: error.message });
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables from your middleware to route handlers using the [res.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) object. If you pass the error object you can check for this in your route handler.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        throw new Error('test error');
    } catch (err) {
        res.locals.Error = err;
    }   
    next(); 
})

app.get('/test', function(req,res,error){
    if (res.locals.Error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: res.locals.Error.message})
    } else {
        res.send("OK");
    }
})
```

Note: You can also pass an error directly to the next() function. Express will skip any remaining handlers if you do this however. See [Express error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

For example:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        throw new Error('test error');
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet is working as expected

```
var a=function test(req,res,next){
    try {
        throw new Error('test error');
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    } 
}

app.get('/test',a, function(req,res){
   res.send(200)
}, (err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(400).send({ error: err.message });
})
```